# Importing "gitlab" package from MeteorJS returns empty object

Tags: meteor, gitlab

I've installed gitlab in my Meteor project with `meteor npm install --save gitlab` and imported the package in the `imports/api/foo.js` file with all the following variations (the comment on the front is the log of the Gitlab object):

```
import Gitlab from 'gitlab';                  // {}
import * as Gitlab from 'gitlab';             // { default: {}, [Symbol(__esModule)]: true }
import { Gitlab } from 'gitlab';              // undefined
const Gitlab = require('gitlab');             // {}
const Gitlab = require('gitlab/dist/es5');    // {}
const Gitlab = require('gitlab/dist/latest'); // {}
```

If I run just `console.log(require('gitlab'))` with NodeJS, I get the correct result.

How am I supposed to import 'gitlab' from a meteor application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue with a clean Meteor 1.8.0.2 project and it is working fine for me:

*/server/main.js:*

```
import Gitlab from 'gitlab'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  console.log(Gitlab) // [Function: Bundle]

  const api = new Gitlab({
    url:   'http://example.com', // Defaults to https://gitlab.com
    token: 'abcdefghij123456'  // Can be created in your profile.
  })

  console.log(api) // full API as in documentation
})
```

So what options do you have here?

- Make sure you use `gitlab` on the server
- Check the `node_modules` folder, whether it is really installed there.
- Try to reset your project using `meteor reset` and then start again so all `node_modules` a rebuild and all Meteor packages are rebuild and the local dev build is rebuild. This will often fix things.
- Create a fresh project and start to reproduce the issue step by step, starting from my working example and change the file structure stepwise to the structure of your project.

Comment: After restarting the server, the program started working, which is weird because I was so sure I had restarted before, but I might be mistaken. Nonetheless, thanks for your tips, I will mark your answer as correct! :)